# Unable to generate signed build using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-signing

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key keycsr from store "C:...\app\csrkeystore.jks": Invalid keystore format

I have put my .jks file in app module and added signing config as:

```
signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias 'keycsr'
                keyPassword '********'
                storeFile file('csrkeystore.jks')
                storePassword '********'
            }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle Android tools expect your signing key to be saved in a Java Keystore File - aka `JKS` format.

The error mesage `Invalid keystore format` indicates that the file `csrkeystore.jks` is not a valid Java Keystore file.

There are a large number of similar formats like PKCS#12, BouncyCastev1, .. that all allow to store private keys, but they are not accepted here.

My recommendation is to download the Java open source tool [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) and open the file `csrkeystore.jks`. It will automatically detect the used file format for a large list of supported key store file types.

Once the file has been loaded you can execute `Tools` -> `Change KeyStore type` -> `JKS` and then save the jks file.

Afterwards it should be possible for Gradle Android tools to read your private signing key.